# TFS Build Server to use separate user for TFS access

Tags: tfs, build-server

I'm trying to set-up a new build server for my TFS 2013 installation.

On a new machine, I've configured a build user:

[image]

On test, this approved the user fine; however, running the readiness checks reports:

[image]

My interpretation of this error is that build.user does not have access to TFS; which is correct.  My question is: can I run the build server using a domain user, but with a separate user for TFS access?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, are you saying that you want a domain user to run the service and it's connection to TFS is somehow impersonated by another user account?

Comment: Why can't you just add the domain account as a TFS user and add it to the builders TFS group?

Comment: It's a complicated and drawn out reason, but if I could do that, I would have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Can I run the build server using a domain user, but with a separate user for TFS access`? Yes, you can and the build service account do not need to have the access to TFS.

Suggest you use *TFSBuild* as the build service account as MSDN recommend.

> *TFSBuild*, which can be a local account, a domain account, or Local
>   Service in a workgroup
>
> This service account is used when builds are configured and when build
>   status information is communicated between the build controller and
>   the build agents. More info for you
>   reference:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253149(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Thanks for this; however, I'm not completely sure how this addresses my specific issue.  When I go into the top screen in my question, it asks what user I want to run the TFS Build Server as, so I give it a domain account that has access to the target server for the build.  However, this user does not have access to the TFS server (or is even on the same domain as the TFS Server).  So, how would I specify the user to communicate with TFS as?